# TFS claims there are merge conflicts even though there are none

Tags: powershell, tfs, teamcity

On TeamCity (I use Enterprise 10.x, if that is relevant), I have a project called `Automerge from Branch A to Branch B`. This project has only one build step, which runs a PowerShell script that executes this command (among others):

```
$tf checkin /comment:"Merging $changesetNumber from Branch A." /recursive /noprompt /bypass /override:"*** Merging from Branch A. ***"
```

(This set-up is necessitated by recent changes in my company's source control hierarchy.)

The build fails on TeamCity, claiming that there are conflicts between some `.cs` files. However, when I compare the files, there are absolutely no differences between them. Example:

[image]

In TFS, `Branch A` and `Branch B` share the same parent, and do not have a parent-child relationship between themselves.

**Questions:**

1. Why does TFS claim that there are merge conflicts even when there are none?
2. How can I ensure that TFS only report actual merge conflicts?

Build failures due to erroneous reports of merge conflicts are highly disruptive to our work flow, and performing manual merges is grossly inefficient.

**EDIT:**

Here are the commands in the Powershell script which is executed in a workspace of `Branch B`:

```
Foreach ($changesetNumber in $changesetsToMerge) {
    echo "*** Getting latest... ***"
    & $tf get /noprompt

    echo "*** Merging $changesetNumber... ***"
    & $tf merge /baseless /version:$changesetNumber~$changesetNumber $/path/to/BranchA . /r /noprompt
    $exitCode=$LastExitCode
    if ($exitCode -ne 0) { exit $exitCode }

    echo "*** Checking in $changesetNumber... ***"
    & $tf checkin /comment:"Merging $changesetNumber from Branch A." /recursive /noprompt /bypass /override:"*** Merging from Branch A. ***"

$exitCode=$LastExitCode
if ($exitCode -ne 0) { exit $exitCode }
```

}

**EDIT:**

I followed the advice [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6a3685a4-3e6e-400d-bae3-c723003f0dc7/merge-conflicts-for-identical-files-?forum=tfsversioncontrol) and added the following line after the command to perform baseless merges:

```
tf resolve /auto:acceptmerge
```

However, it did not work because of the following error:

```
[12:58:28]path\to\file.cs: The source and target both have changes.
```

As mentioned previously, the source version is identical to the target version, as shown during comparison. Nonetheless, TFS returns the aforementioned error message.

Comment: 1. Your one step is to do a checkin?  It looks like you haven't pended any changes to checkin?  Where's the `tf merge` command that pends the changes?  2. Are you changes the contents of both branches to be identical?  ie, is the common ancestor different?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Thanks for your reply. 1. There is a previous command that merges the changes from Branch A to Branch B before I run the command that performs the check-in. I simply didn't include that earlier command because I thought it wasn't relevant, but if it is, then I will edit my post to include it. 2. The common ancestor is the same.

Comment: 1. That would be great - it would be helpful to see thee merge command since that's the command that actually generates the conflicts, even though the checkin is failing because of them.  2. If all three are the same, then you shouldn't get conflicts unless you are using the `/baseless` option, for example.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I have updated the post with more details. As you can see, I run the ``tf merge`` command with the ``/baseless`` flag. I will try your suggestion to exclude the ``/baseless`` flag tomorrow.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Just realised that removing the ``/baseless`` flag is not an option -- ``Branch A`` and ``Branch B`` both have the same parent, but do not have a parent-child relationship between themselves.